# How to resolve "Uncaught TypeError" in error handler using CakePHP 2 on PHP7?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

**Fatal Error**

> Error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to ErrorHandler::handleException() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/quiz/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php:108 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: ErrorHandler::handleException(Object(Error)) #1 {main} thrown
>
> > File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/quiz/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php
> >         Line: 108

I am using cakephp 2.6.1 on php7. I am getting above error.
please help me out

Comment: when you getting above error. Plese provide proper description

Comment: CakePHP v2.x is not compatible with PHP-7. Mainly because it has `String` class which is reserved in PHP7.

Comment: Bogdan Kuštan - Just change String to CakeString, and there is at least one other class that has the same problem. This will not solve every php7 issue, but gets you going.

Answer (score 4):

CakePHP 2.8 is compatible with PHP7. CakePHP 2.6 and 2.7 are not.
See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-8-migration-guide.html#php7-compatibility

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13703335)

Comment: Hm, I don't agree with that.
My answer _is_ the answer, because there is no more to say about that issue. You suggest to use this web link (to the official cake documentation …!) only for reference. That's exactly why I added it. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: I don't think argue much. It's a little questionable to me.

Comment: not helpful, since 2.8 is no longer available. The only upgrade path from 2.x to 4.x is a nightmare. Better to trash Cake and start over. Need to know what is causing the specific incompatibility so that it might be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I made these two changes to cake 2.2.5 to fix fatal error handling using php7. It's not exhaustively tested, but it seems to patch the problem.

/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php

```
public static function handleException( $exception ) {  // remove Exception hint
```

/lib/Cake/Error/ExceptionRenderer.php

```
public function __construct( $exception ) { // remove Exception hint
```

Answer (score -1):

**Yii Framewor**k --> I have merged code and forget to remove HEAD that is due to conflicts while merging. By removing it, my code start working